# Power in AC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, frequency

Why is the frequency of $IV$ twice the frequency of $I$ and $V$ individually, when they are in phase? I can't see why just from looking at the equation for power:

$$P = IV = \cos^2(2\pi \,f\, t)$$

And apparently it's obvious, making it surprisingly difficult to google. But I'm not seeing it, so thanks for any help or resources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current and voltage can be negative.  A complete AC cycle includes two voltage peaks: one positive and one negative.

Power is never negative.  The periods of negative voltage become periods of positive power.  This means the power frequency is doubled compared to voltage and current.

From http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ACPowerFactorPrinciple/
[image]